# ¿Por que no me funciona el return? JAVA POO

Tags: java, poo

Estaba haciendo una calculadora , pero cuando llamo al método sumar , restar , etc, no me devuelve su resultado .Al resto de los métodos los puse tipo void y a su resultado lo puse en un `system.out.println` , ya se  que no se debe hacer eso , por que el void no devuelve un valor , nada. ¿Entonces que puede ser ?

```
public class Calculadora {
    private int operador1;
    private int operador2;

    public Calculadora(){
    };

    public Calculadora (int  operador1 , int operador2){
        this.operador1 = operador1;
        this.operador2 = operador2;
    }
    public int sumar(){
        int suma =0;
        suma = operador1 + operador2;
        return suma;
    }
    public int sumar (int operador1 ,int operador2){
        int suma = 0;
        suma = operador1 + operador2;
        return suma;
    }
    public int restar (){
        int resta =0;
        resta = operador1 - operador2;
        return resta;
    }
    public int restar (int operador1 , int operador2){
        int resta =0;
        resta = operador1 - operador2;
        return resta;
    }
    public int multiplicar (){
        int multiplicar = 0;
        multiplicar = operador1 * operador2;
        return multiplicar;
    }
    public int multiplicar (int operador1 , int operador2){
        int multiplicar = 0;
        multiplicar = operador1 * operador2;
        return multiplicar;
    }
    public double dividir (){
        double dividir = 0;
        dividir = operador1 / operador2;
        if (operador2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("No se puede dividir por cero");
        }
        return dividir;
    }
    public double dividir (double numerador , double divisor){
        double dividir  = 0;
        dividir = numerador / divisor;
        if(divisor == 0){
            System.out.println("No se puede dividir por cero");
        }
        return dividir;
    }
    public void esPositivo(){
        if ( operador1 > 0 && operador2 > 0){
            System.out.println("Es positivo");
        }
    }
    public void  potencia (int base , int indice){
    int potencia = 0;
    for(int i= 0 ; i <indice ; i++) {
        potencia = (int) Math.pow(base, indice);}
        System.out.println(potencia);
    }
    public void sumatoria (int limit , int numero) {
        int sumatoria =0;
        int suma=0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++) {
            if(numero<limit) {
                suma++;
            }
            sumatoria+=suma;
        }
        System.out.println(sumatoria);
    }
    public void sumatoria (int limitInferior , int limitSuperior , int numero) {
        int suma = 0;
        int sumatoria=0;
        for(limitInferior = 0 ; limitInferior <limitSuperior ; limitInferior++) {
            if(numero>limitInferior && numero<limitSuperior) {
                suma++;
            }
            sumatoria+=suma;
        }
        System.out.println(sumatoria);
    }
    public void productoria (int limit , int numero ) {
        int productoria=1;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++) {
            if(numero <limit) {
                productoria*=numero;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(productoria);    
    }

    public void productoria (int limitInferior , int limitSuperior , int numero) {
        int productoria=1;
        for(limitInferior = 0 ; limitInferior <limitSuperior ; limitInferior++) {
            if(numero>limitInferior && numero<limitSuperior) {
                productoria*=numero;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(productoria);
    }
    public void contarDivisores (int numero1 , int numero2) {
        int divisores = 0;
        int suma1 = 0;
        int suma2=0;
        int par=0 ;
        int impar=0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
            if(numero1 %numero2==0) {
                if(numero2%2==0) {
                    par+=numero2;
                    suma1=par;
                    System.out.println(suma1);
                }else{
                    impar+=numero2;
                    suma2+=impar;
                    System.out.println(suma2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void factorial (int numero) {
        int factorial = 1 ;
        do{
            factorial*=numero;
            numero= numero-1;
        }while(numero!=0);
        System.out.println(factorial);
     }
}

public class PruebaCalculadora {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculadora c1 = new Calculadora(10, 2);
        c1.sumar(); 
        c1.restar();
        c1.dividir();
        c1.multiplicar();
        c1.esPositivo();
        c1.potencia(2, 8);
        c1.sumatoria(10, 5);
        c1.sumatoria(1, 10, 9);
        c1.productoria(2, 4);
        c1.productoria(10, 20, 15);
        c1.contarDivisores(10, 2);
        c1.factorial(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes @computer96, a que te refieres con que no te retorna nada , a cuando haces `c1.sumar();` no realiza ninguna acción, osea no va tu método de la clase Calculadora para retornar el valor de suma ?, esto seria ideal que lo asignes a alguna variable o uses un break para seguir paso a paso tu método, ya que así como esta solo llamarías al método y nada mas.

Comment: holaa , si claro cuando llamo al método sumar(); , aunque también probé con el otro método sumar que puedo poner por parámetros los números que quiero que sumen .Y donde tendría que poner un break dentro del método  o donde?

Comment: Así es puedes colocarlo dentro del método en si al principio e ir paso a paso viendo que se esta realizando, aunque te recomiendo seguir la respuesta de @Manflack e ir imprimiendo los resultados para una verificación rápida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error está en
`public class PruebaCalculadora {
    public static void main(String[] args) {`

Tú llamas a los métodos de c1 sumar, restar, dividir, multiplicar y no muestras sus resultados.
Si a la hora de enviarle como parámetro `Calculadora c1 = new Calculadora(10,0);`
Tu programa mostrará como resultado

> No se puede dividir por cero.

Trata de que, en cada llamada a cualquier método que hagas

1. Retorne un valor.
2. Dentro del método, no llames a un `System.out.println("");`

Dentro del void main, prueba con esto:

```
System.out.println(c1.sumar());
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora si funciona :D, le tenia que poner un system.out.println en la parte del main a cada metodo como me dijiste . Ahora te hago otra pregunta cuando se que tengo que llamar al metodo junto  con el system.out.println y cuando no? por que a veces con otros programas los llamos sin tener que ponerlo con el system.

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado.
Mira, tú haz creado un método, ¿verdad? Si miras detenidamente, haz definido que esos métodos son de tipo String, Int, etc... Y haz hecho un retorno de valores. Eso implica dos cosas.
 1. Que el tipo de dato que retornes va a ser igual al tipo de dato de tu función y que:
 2. Tu método, va a tener las características de una variable.
¿Qué implica esto? Que va a tener temporalmente un valor.
Es decir, a la hora de hacer retorno, va a dar como resultado un valor. Y si no es guardado, o en este caso, "impreso", lo vas a perder.

Comment: Ah Buenisimo gracias por tu buena onda , Saludos :D